# Change the nanosecond markers in the timeline from 00:32 to 00:30

Tags: timeline

When you press CRTL + T inside the timeline, it changes from displaying frames to displaying seconds and nanoseconds. I have seen that without closely zooming in, the nanosecond and normal second markers are placed at every 00:32 nanosecond, and not every 30 seconds, so, half a second.

I personally want to place a key frame every half a second, every 30 nanoseconds, which means that I always have to zoom in very closely in the timeline to find the right nanosecond.

I wanted to ask if it is possible to change the white nanosecond and second time markers from 00:32 to 00:30 and so on. This is more of a comfort thing and not a bug or a problem, but it would still be helpful, so I don't have to always zoom in..

To show it clearly, I want to change this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Of course, set to their correct frame / nanosecond position.

Comment: Hello, it seems you misunderstood what the number after the + sign is. They're not nanoseconds (?) but the number of frames since the last second elapsed. This displayed number is dependent on the timeline zoom level which you can change with CTRL + middle mouse while hovering over the timeline, and the number of frames per second, which you can change in the Format panel of the scene output properties. But do note you can't set a keyframe to a particular second or half of a second, keyframes are set on frames, which are independant of the framerate, while time is not.

Comment: additionaly to what Gorgious wrote - you doesn't seem to know what a nanosecond is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond#:~:text=A%20nanosecond%20(ns)%20is%20a,nanogram%2C%20nanometre%2C%20etc.) What you see in Blender cannot be nanoseconds - that's for sure.

Comment: @Chris and Gorgious Thank you for the clarification. So, is it possible to change the white displayed numbers, including the ones after the +, even when zooming outside? Essentially my original request, like seen in the second picture.

Comment: As Gorgious wrote - you set keyframes to frames, not to a time. So i think one way to do what you want would be to zoom exactly in that way, that your chosen framerate fits with your time, so that your displayed time always "hits" a keyframe. But i think you don't want that...

Comment: @Chris well yes, I want to set my key frames exactly at half a second, a full second, a full and half a second, 2 seconds, and so on and so forth, I just wanted to change the visual appearance of blender and that part of the timeline to fit better to this workflow, so I don't have to zoom exactly in in the first place.

( I know that I am still setting the keyframes to frames and not to a time, its just more comfortable for me )

I am sorry if this is more of a confusing question or unusual question. I am still thankful for your time investment.